# How to determine the joint PDF of two uniformly distributed random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on the set:
$$D=\{(x,y): 1\leqslant x\leqslant 2,~ 0\leqslant y\leqslant 2,~ x \leqslant y\}$$
I want to determine the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ but I'm not sure how to do that.
EDIT:
I've drawn the figure, and the area that respects all the conditions given by the set D is a rectangle with an area of 2. This would mean that the PDF is 1/2. Is this correct?

Comment: The PDF is $\frac 1  A$ on $D$ where $A$ is the area of $D$. Draw a picture and find the area.

Comment: If ever a question was ambiguous, this one is. Your title and your initial sentence and your statement about $f_X$ seem to imply that you mean $X$ is uniformly distributed and $Y$ is uniformly distributed, but then your definition of $D$ seems to suggest you mean that the pair $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed (and that would imply that $X$ is _not_ uniformly distributed and $Y$ is _not_ uniformly distributed).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've drawn the figure, and the area that respects all the conditions given by the set D is a rectangle with an area of 2. This would mean that the PDF is 1/2. Is this correct?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The statement is about pairs of random variables, I wrote the formula about $f_{X}$ because I wanted to make a connection between the case of a single uniform r.v., thinking it would be somewhat relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
D &= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:1 \le x \le 2, 0 \le y \le 2, x \le y \}\\
&=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 1 \le x \le 2, x \le y \le 2 \}
\end{align}

[image]

The area of the triangle is $\frac12 \cdot (2-1)\cdot (2-1)=\frac12$.

Hence the joint pdf is

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2 &, 1 \le x \le 2, x \le y \le 2 \\ 0 &, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$